# Depend on the binary of another workspace package being built by cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, build-script

I have a workspace project with multiple packages. The two important ones are:

- `flowc` - which is a lib and a binary
- `flowstdlib`

`flowc` is a kind of compiler that I build as part of the project.

`flowstdlib` has a build script, that uses the `flowc` built binary to build that package (generate "code", files etc), so I need the `flowc` compiler ready when `flowstdlib` is to be built.

In `cargo.toml` of `flowstdlib` I define `flowc` as a build dependency:

```
[build-dependencies]
flowc = {path = "../flowc", version = "0.31.0" }`
```

(I've tried making it also a dependency, but no change)

in the `build.rs` of `flowstdlib` I look for it in the path, and if not found in the `../target/debug/flowc` location:

```
    let flowc = if Path::new(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR")).join("../target/debug/flowc").exists() {
        "../target/debug/flowc"
    } else if Simpath::new("PATH").find_type("flowc", FileType::File).is_ok() {
        "flowc"
    } else {
        ""
    };
```

When I run the build, it looks like it's trying to build multiple packages at the same time in parallel:

```
   Compiling flowstdlib v0.31.0 (/Users/andrew/workspace/flow/flowstdlib)
   Compiling flowsamples v0.31.1 (/Users/andrew/workspace/flow/samples)
warning: Could not find `flowc` in $PATH or `target/debug`, so cannot build flowstdlib
error: failed to run custom build command for `flowsamples v0.31.1 (/Users/andrew/workspace/flow/samples)`
```

and the `flowstdlib` build fails as `flowc` binary is not built yet.

Since the build continues and eventually finishes building `flowc`, if I re-run the build, it will work the second time around (as `flowc` binary is now found).

So:

- it looks like a `build-dependency` does wait for the depended-on binary to be built (maybe it waits for the library to be built, hard to tell)

## Question

How I can make the build of `flowstdlib` wait for the completion of the `flowc` binary?
(without forcing a non-parallel build)

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to depend on binaries in Cargo. Have you considered refactoring the core logic of `flowc` into a library, and depending on that?

Comment: There's an RFC posted just last week about adding support for depending on binaries to Cargo: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3028

Comment: flowc already has the core in a library. I would need to then invoke it from build.rs without calling the binary - could be done but not ideal. Thanks for the idea @LambdaFairy

Comment: Thanks @KevinReid I will check out that PR and see if it might land in a reasonable time

Answer (score 3):

Pending the RFC landing, my workaround is to split the build into two commands (I'm using a Makefile to invoke them currently):

```
* cargo build -p flowc   # will complete the build of the flowc binary
* cargo build            # will build the entire workspace, including flowstdlib
```